# Changing dynamic textfield inside button in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

I am having some problems getting this code to work properly. I want to change the text on a textfield inside a button. It works, but only for the upState. As soon as I hover or click the button, it changes back to the original name. Is there any way I can define it as anyState?

```
var doc:DisplayObjectContainer = m1.upState as DisplayObjectContainer;
var tf:TextField = doc.getChildAt(1) as TextField;

var boldText:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
boldText.bold = true;

tf.text = "Sterno Cleido Mastoid";
tf.setTextFormat(boldText);
```

Example:
http://www.testdummies.dk/dynamictext.fla

Comment: If you're creating you're button in Flash on the timeline, try putting your text field on it's own layer with no keyframes across the different button states.

Comment: Post your fla file for better assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your code is only changing the text for the up state of the button.  The other states remain unaffected.

You could simply copy and paste your code to do the same change for the over and down states - adding this code after your existing code would do just that:

```
doc = m1.overState as DisplayObjectContainer;
tf = doc.getChildAt(1) as TextField;
tf.text = "Neck";
tf.setTextFormat(boldText);

doc = m1.downState as DisplayObjectContainer;
tf = doc.getChildAt(1) as TextField;
tf.text = "Neck";
tf.setTextFormat(boldText);
```

This is an awkward way though to code a simple text change for a button. Creating a custom button class, or even making a movieClip work as a button would be much cleaner.  Create a new question if you need help learning either of these things.

Comment: What I am actually going to do is change all button text in a for loop. I have a xml file with different languages and I will tell flash which language to use via JS. So its not really just 1 button, but around 15. As in example, each button has a very specific hitbox (an odd shape) and I have been told that movieclips does not support this. Seems I will need to do copy paste code for each state..

Comment: Got it working just fine with copy paste. As I'm using a for loop, its not that much code :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would put the text field on its own layer on top of the button, so it always has the same text regardless of button state.

or, alternatively, you could copy and paste that code into each button state and then alter the code to reflect the current state. (the first solution is faster/easier though)